# How capacitor can be used to store data permanently in hard disk?

Tags: capacitor

How capacitor store data in hard disk if we use it? According to me when we will power up the computer capacitor will get discharged and data should have been erased? Can anyone explain, why don't get erased?

Comment: Capacitors don't store data in hard disks, data is stored in magnetic domains

Comment: I think that perhaps you are confusing dynamic RAM (DRAM) with a hard drive. Wikipedia should help clear up the difference.

Comment: Technically, floating-gate CMOS is capacitor-based storage.  This is one of those things that just doesn't translate into English, even though most of us here speak it. Pravin, is this question about solid-state hard disk storage?

Comment: @bdegnan No this was not related to solid state hard disk. I heard that we can use capacitor to store data permanently. How can we store using capacitor when capacitor gets discharged after time t and our data will be lost.

And you said cmos capacitor based hard disk but capacitor should gets discharged. why our data on hard drive doesn't lost.?

Comment: @PravinKumar You cannot use a capacitor to store data permanently unless you are using some FLASH technique (storage ~10years for 0.1% charge drift) or SONOS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SONOS storage time ~25years for 0.1% charge drift)  If your question is not related to a solid state hard disk, there's no "hard disk" that exists by your description.

Answer (score 3):

Large capacitors are sometimes used to give disk-drives time to flush ram-based caches back to disk after a power failure.  The disk itself doesn't need power to retain the data once the capacitor is discharged.

Answer (score 1):

The storage mechanism of a hard disk has nothing to do with capacitance.  Bits are stored by small magnetic domains being polarized one way or the other.